# Converting Secret Key into a String and Vice Versa

Tags: java, string, encryption

I am generating a key and need to store it in DB, so I convert it into a String, but to get back the key from the String. What are the possible ways of accomplishing this?

My code is,

```
SecretKey key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
String stringKey=key.toString();
System.out.println(stringKey);
```

How can I get the key back from the String?

Comment: Note that conversion of keys to string should only be performed when absolutely necessary. There is no explicit method for destroying `String` instances in Java while key objects and byte arrays may be cleared. This means that keys could stay available within memory for a longer period of time. Using a (password protected) `KeyStore`, preferably one backed by the runtime system / OS or even hardware should be preferred.

Answer (score 338, accepted):

You can convert the `SecretKey` to a byte array (`byte[]`), then Base64 encode that to a `String`.  To convert back to a `SecretKey`, Base64 decode the String and use it in a `SecretKeySpec` to rebuild your original `SecretKey`.

### For Java 8

**SecretKey to String:**

```
// create new key
SecretKey secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();
// get base64 encoded version of the key
String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded());
```

**String to SecretKey:**

```
// decode the base64 encoded string
byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey);
// rebuild key using SecretKeySpec
SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");
```

---

### For Java 7 and before (including Android):

**NOTE I:** you can skip the Base64 encoding/decoding part and just store the `byte[]` in SQLite.  That said, performing Base64 encoding/decoding is not an expensive operation and you can store strings in almost any DB without issues.

**NOTE II:** Earlier Java versions do not include a Base64 in one of the `java.lang` or `java.util` packages. It is however possible to use codecs from [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/), [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) or [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava).

**SecretKey to String:**

```
// CREATE NEW KEY
// GET ENCODED VERSION OF KEY (THIS CAN BE STORED IN A DB)

    SecretKey secretKey;
    String stringKey;

    try {secretKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey();}
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {/* LOG YOUR EXCEPTION */}

    if (secretKey != null) {stringKey = Base64.encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT)}
```

**String to SecretKey:**

```
// DECODE YOUR BASE64 STRING
// REBUILD KEY USING SecretKeySpec

    byte[] encodedKey     = Base64.decode(stringKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
    SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length, "AES");
```

Comment: @Jabari What is the package for "Base64" class

Comment: @SwapL It's android.util.Base64.  Check out this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead Most people aren't using Java 8 yet.  I used this in Android, which definitely isn't on 8 yet (and probably won't be for some time).  Please don't edit someone's answer on an assumption of context.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead Your comment completely ignores the first sentence of mine: "Most people aren't using Java 8 yet".  Your answer will throw exception errors for the vast majority of Java users, Android and non-Android alike.  That said, your suggestion of adding a snippet in addition to the current answer would provide a more complete solution.  FYI, I'm not "sentimental" in regards to my answer.  As a matter of fact, I swapped DES for AES because it's a definite improvement security wise (as well as being more in line with the code in the original question).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead  Again...what you added will throw "NoSuchAlgorithmException" exception errors.  Please See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html  I will fix...

Comment: I know, and anybody that knows Java will know how to handle a checked exception, but I'll create an `IllegalStateException` as AES should always be present...

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead Are you trying this in versions outside of Java 8???  I'm running it in several different places without issue in Java 6, Java 7, and Android.  At least 45 others are as well.  What errors are you getting (if you are running outside Java 8)???

Comment: Hi Jabari , when i do `SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES"); 
`     I get error saying `Required SecretKey , provided SecretKeySpec`  . please update solution. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

To show how much fun it is to create some functions that are *fail fast* I've written the following 3 functions.

One creates an AES key, one encodes it and one decodes it back. These three methods can be used with Java 8 (without dependence of internal classes or outside dependencies):

```
public static SecretKey generateAESKey(int keysize)
        throws InvalidParameterException {
    try {
        if (Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES") < keysize) {
            // this may be an issue if unlimited crypto is not installed
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Key size of " + keysize
                    + " not supported in this runtime");
        }

        final KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keyGen.init(keysize);
        return keyGen.generateKey();
    } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // AES functionality is a requirement for any Java SE runtime
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "AES should always be present in a Java SE runtime", e);
    }
}

public static SecretKey decodeBase64ToAESKey(final String encodedKey)
        throws IllegalArgumentException {
    try {
        // throws IllegalArgumentException - if src is not in valid Base64
        // scheme
        final byte[] keyData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey);
        final int keysize = keyData.length * Byte.SIZE;

        // this should be checked by a SecretKeyFactory, but that doesn't exist for AES
        switch (keysize) {
        case 128:
        case 192:
        case 256:
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key size for AES: " + keysize);
        }

        if (Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES") < keysize) {
            // this may be an issue if unlimited crypto is not installed
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Key size of " + keysize
                    + " not supported in this runtime");
        }

        // throws IllegalArgumentException - if key is empty
        final SecretKeySpec aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyData, "AES");
        return aesKey;
    } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // AES functionality is a requirement for any Java SE runtime
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "AES should always be present in a Java SE runtime", e);
    }
}

public static String encodeAESKeyToBase64(final SecretKey aesKey)
        throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (!aesKey.getAlgorithm().equalsIgnoreCase("AES")) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not an AES key");
    }

    final byte[] keyData = aesKey.getEncoded();
    final String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keyData);
    return encodedKey;
}
```

Comment: Note that storing / retrieving keys may not work if the key store is on a hardware security module (or any other location where `getEncoded()` is not available).

Answer (score 2):

Actually what Luis proposed did not work for me. I had to figure out another way. This is what helped me. Might help you too. 
Links:

1. *.getEncoded(): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/Key.html
2. Encoder information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html
3. Decoder information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html

Code snippets:
For encoding:

```
String temp = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(key.getEncoded()));
```

For decoding:

```
byte[] encodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(temp);
SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length, "DES");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `.toString()`.

Notice that SecretKey inherits from java.security.Key, which itself inherits from Serializable. So the key here (no pun intended) is to serialize the key into a ByteArrayOutputStream, get the byte[] array and store it into the db. The reverse process would be to get the byte[] array off the db, create a ByteArrayInputStream offf the byte[] array, and deserialize the SecretKey off it...

... or even simpler, just use the `.getEncoded()` method inherited from java.security.Key (which is a parent interface of SecretKey). This method returns the encoded byte[] array off Key/SecretKey, which you can store or retrieve from the database.

This is all assuming your SecretKey implementation supports encoding. Otherwise, `getEncoded()` will return null.

## edit:

You should look at the Key/SecretKey javadocs (available right at the start of a google page):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/Key.html

Or this from CodeRanch (also found with the same google search):

http://www.coderanch.com/t/429127/java/java/Convertion-between-SecretKey-String-or

Comment: Serializable is an anti pattern these days IMO whenever you had an alternative approach. The approved answer which base64 encodes and decodes it is far better.

Answer (score 0):

**Converting SecretKeySpec to String and vice-versa:** 
you can use `getEncoded()` method in `SecretKeySpec` which will give `byteArray`, from that you can use `encodeToString()` to get `string` value of `SecretKeySpec` in `Base64` object.

While converting `SecretKeySpec` to `String`: use `decode()` in `Base64` will give `byteArray`, from that you can create instance for `SecretKeySpec` with the params as the `byteArray` to reproduce your `SecretKeySpec`.

```
String mAesKey_string;
SecretKeySpec mAesKey= new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

//SecretKeySpec to String 
    byte[] byteaes=mAesKey.getEncoded();
    mAesKey_string=Base64.encodeToString(byteaes,Base64.NO_WRAP);

//String to SecretKeySpec
    byte[] aesByte = Base64.decode(mAesKey_string, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    mAesKey= new SecretKeySpec(aesByte, "AES");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it's work without Base64 ( that is included only in JDK 1.8 ), this code run also in the previous java version :)

```
private static String SK = "Secret Key in HEX";


//  To Encrupt

public static String encrypt( String Message ) throws Exception{

    byte[] KeyByte = hexStringToByteArray( SK);
    SecretKey k = new SecretKeySpec(KeyByte, 0, KeyByte.length, "DES");

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DES","SunJCE");
    c.init(1, k);
    byte mes_encrypted[] = cipher.doFinal(Message.getBytes());

    String MessageEncrypted = byteArrayToHexString(mes_encrypted);
    return MessageEncrypted;
}

//  To Decrypt

public static String decrypt( String MessageEncrypted )throws Exception{

    byte[] KeyByte = hexStringToByteArray( SK );
    SecretKey k = new SecretKeySpec(KeyByte, 0, KeyByte.length, "DES");

    Cipher dcr =  Cipher.getInstance("DES","SunJCE");
    dc.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
    byte[] MesByte  = hexStringToByteArray( MessageEncrypted );
    byte mes_decrypted[] = dcipher.doFinal( MesByte );
    String MessageDecrypeted = new String(mes_decrypted);

    return MessageDecrypeted;
}

public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte bytes[]){

    StringBuffer hexDump = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++){
    if(bytes[i] < 0)
    {   
        hexDump.append(getDoubleHexValue(Integer.toHexString(256 - Math.abs(bytes[i]))).toUpperCase());
    }else
    {
        hexDump.append(getDoubleHexValue(Integer.toHexString(bytes[i])).toUpperCase());
    }
    return hexDump.toString();

}



public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {

    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2)
    {   
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;

}
```