# convert Byte Array to Secret Key

Tags: java, byte, secret-key

I've been trying to convert a byte array to its original SecretKey, but I've no more ideas left. The most promising attempt was this one:

```
byte[] encodedKey     = Base64.decode(stringKey);
SecretKey originalKey = SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length, "AES")
```

found here: [Converting Secret Key into a String and Vice Versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355466/converting-secret-key-into-a-string-and-vice-versa)

I'm using the import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec, so the constructor for SecretKeySpec should be used correctly, at least referring to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html.

Nonetheless I always get "The Method SecretKeySpec is undefined for ... [Class Name]" - which I just don't get.

I'm guessing it's just some minor mistake, but I just can't figure it out. Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Do you have a semi-colon at the end of the constructor? :)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You need to use the `new` keyword to call the constructor and create the object.

```
SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length, "AES");
```

When you try to call it without `new`, the compiler thinks it might be a method you've defined inside that class, hence your error message.

Comment: I know, still - it's good to know not to be alone ;-) thanks again!

Comment: Can you please say why you opted to use the 4-parameter constructor instead of `public SecretKeySpec(byte[] key, String algorithm)`? [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html#SecretKeySpec(byte[],%20java.lang.String)). Thanks!