# Android's KeyStore getKey returning null

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa

I use this small snippet to store a KeyPair in Android's keystore :

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(null);
Certificate[] cert = new Certificate[1];
cert[0] = getCertificate(kp);
ks.setKeyEntry(PRIVATE_KEY_TAG, kp.getPrivate(), null, cert);
ks.setKeyEntry(PUBLIC_KEY_TAG, kp.getPublic(), null, cert);
```

But when i fetch a key from KeyStore, with `ks.getKey(PUBLIC_KEY_TAG, null).getEncoded()`, i get this exception :

```
Attempt to invoke interface method Key.getEncoded() on a null object
```

And when i try to encrypt a String through a Cipher, i get a :

```
Unknow key type passed to RSA
```

Any idea on why this KeyStore is causing problems ? 
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355466/converting-secret-key-into-a-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: This is about converting Keys to Strings, i might use it in the future but i don't think it will help me with this problem, but thanks btw

Comment: @Krupal Ugh, different times, 44 points for that horrid code example, I had to rewrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [retrieve the public key from the certificate instead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/cert/Certificate.html#getPublicKey%28%29). Key stores can be used to store the private key / certificate you hold yourself, or a trusted certificate of another entity. Java (and Android) key stores are mainly targeted at X5.09 based PKI. Storing a public key with a certificate does not make sense, the public key is already contained within the certificate.

So instead try:

```
ks.getCertificate(PRIVATE_KEY_TAG).getPublicKey().getEncoded();
```

Comment: Yeah, but i still have to store the certificate, which is not working. And I still won't be able to get the private key from the certificate right ?

Comment: YOu can store the private key and cert, get the cert and then get the public key. Just a second, I'll update...

Comment: That's a good optimization, however my problem is that i can't fetch anything from KeyStore, so i won't be able to fetch PrivateKey, any clue ?

Comment: Yay, it's working this way, you rocks. I can't understand why this error occurs tho, but as long as it works... Thanks again !

Comment: Storing public keys is just not really supported. With `getKey` it looks for a private key with corresponding cert.

Comment: I see, it seems logical this way. Thanks ;)

Comment: I'm getting this problem again, when i quit the application and start it back, it seems like KeyStore delete its content when app stop, is it possible ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67392/discussion-between-maarten-bodewes-owlstead-and-rogue).