# How to add GeneratedKey to config.properties file?

Tags: java, properties-file, key-generator

I'm trying to encrypt & decrypt password and for these generating key so far so good.Now I need to store this key in properties file but when I add the key it look like this :

```
#Tue Nov 01 08:22:52 EET 2016
KEY=\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000
```

So I suspect from my code maybe something wrong ?!?!

**And there is a part of my code =**

```
private byte[] key = new byte[16];

public void addProperties(String x, String z) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    String propertiesFileName = "config.properties";
    try {
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(propertiesFileName);
        properties.setProperty(x, z);
        properties.store(out, null);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void generateKey() {
    KeyGenerator keygen;
    SecretKey secretKey;
    byte[] keybyte = new byte[64];
    try {
        keygen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        keygen.init(128);
        secretKey = keygen.generateKey();
        keybyte = secretKey.getEncoded();
        key = keybyte;

 //THIS METHOD ADDING PROP TO PROPERTIES FILE
        addProperties("KEY", new String(key));

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

***Thanks for help.All answers acceptable.***

Comment: are u using eclipse?

Comment: Yes, Eclipse Neon

Comment: Can you try this line to convert `bytes[]` to `String`?

`addProperties("KEY", new String(keybyte, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Comment: Thank u for replay.Of corse, now I will try and inform u

Comment: Same result : '#Tue Nov 01 08:56:39 EET 2016
KEY=\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`KeyGenerator#generateKey()` has return type of [`SecretKey`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/SecretKey.html) and from javadocs

> Keys that implement this interface return the string RAW as their
>   encoding format (see getFormat), and return the raw key bytes as the
>   result of a getEncoded method call. (The getFormat and getEncoded
>   methods are inherited from the java.security.Key parent interface.)

[`So you need to convert them and there is already asked question on this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355466/converting-secret-key-into-a-string-and-vice-versa)

`String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secretKey.getEncoded());`

`SecretKey originalKey = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");`

Comment: `#Tue Nov 01 09:19:13 EET 2016
KEY=Ja017HB2g8XPrzRwqj4uQw\=\=`