# com.google.gson.Gson class fails with javax.crypto.SecretKey?

Tags: java, android, gson, javax.crypto

I have stored the `SecretKey` during some encryption operation which I need to use later. While storing I am converting it into string :

```
String keyAsString = new Gson().toJson(key);
```

But while retriving it fails for following code :

```
   SecretKey secKey =  new Gson().fromJson(keyAsString, SecretKey.class);
```

Also I am not getting any single hint in LogCat even with Verbose messaging filter. I tried surrounding the code in try catch as below with debug points ( In hope I may get any exception trace while debugging ) :

```
try {
SecretKey secKey =  new Gson().fromJson(keyAsString, SecretKey.class); // One debug point here
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e)); // And one debug point here
}
```

But debugger do not stop at both the debug points, Immediately on device app crashes and shows unfortunately application crashed message.

The json structure on save for `SecretKey` is as follow :

```
{
  "algorithm": "AES",
  "key": [
   integer1, integre2, ....
  ]
}
```

Note : integer1, integer2 ... are actual numbers for security purpose I am not posting the original result numbers.

What may have gone wrong ? Is such storing of `SecretKey` is not allowed ?

**Update**

Converting SecretKey to json string & vice versa using Gson was bad Idea as answered by jonathanrz below I followed his answer & wrote two utility functions in android to convert SecretKey to String & vice versa functions are as follows :

```
public static String secretKeyToString(SecretKey key) {
  return Base64.encodeToString(key.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}

public static SecretKey encodedStringToSecretKey(String encodedKey) {
  byte[] decodedKey = Base64.decode(encodedKey, Base64.DEFAULT);
  return new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");
}
```

Comment: Can you post an example of a json that you are trying to parse?

Comment: @jonathanrz please have look at the edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the key as a string and then use the [SecretKeyFactory.translateKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/SecretKeyFactory.html#translateKey(javax.crypto.SecretKey)) to parse the key.

UPDATE: after you edited your question, I saw that the output you have are not just a single String. So you will need to create a class that represents your json, parse the response with it and construct each key with translateKey. GSON can only parse a json if the class has the attributes with the same name and same type as the keys in json, what is not the case for SecretKey.

UPDATE2: translateKey can't create keys from String. The option to create a key from a String is this: [Converting Secret Key into a String and Vice Versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5355466/converting-secret-key-into-a-string-and-vice-versa)

Comment: Is there any other safe alternative on android to store the SecretKey except making use of Gson ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: @pcj where do you want to store it?

Comment: In SQLite database, currently I am storing the Gson string result as string in SQLite db & trying to retrieve using Gson which fails.

Comment: @jonatharz thank you very much you saved my day, its difficult when we don't see any error or exception message in LogCat and code fails, thanks again :)

Comment: @pcj gladly to help