# Can someone tell me how I use a RC4 key string to create the key again?

Tags: java, rc4-cipher

Please help me :(, I am trying this answer in this post [Converting string to SecretKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305410/converting-string-to-secretkey)

But it doesn't seem to be working for RC4, please tell me what I am doing wrong.
This is my RC4 class in a separate file:

```
public class RC4 {
    SecretKey k;


    public RC4() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
       KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC4");
       k = kg.generateKey();
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(final byte[] plaintext) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");  // Transformation of the algorithm
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
        byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
        return cipherBytes;
    }

    public byte[] decrypt(final byte[] ciphertext) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RC4");
          cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
          byte[] plainBytes = cipher.doFinal(ciphertext);
          return plainBytes;
    }
    
    public SecretKey getK() {
        return k;
    }

    public void setK(SecretKey k) {
        this.k = k;
    }

}
```

This code below is also from another file in a main method

```
RC4 rc4Client = new RC4();
SecretKey k = rc4Client.getK();

String encodedK = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(k.getEncoded());

//print
System.out.println("Random k: " + k.toString());

byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedK);
k = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "RC4");

//print
System.out.println("Random k: " + k.toString());
```

The printed output is:

```
Random k: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@2c97f72b
Random k: javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fffe4170
```

They should be the same, why are they different??

Comment: You are seeing a default implementation of toString() method in Object class, SecretKey does not override that, you should look into getEncoded() and getFormat() methods of SecretKey.

Comment: I have looked into it did what this answer say for Java 8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305410/converting-string-to-secretkey, but I still couldn't get the back the same key after encoding and decoding from string to key and vice versa :(

Comment: Just to make this clear... what do you mean by "same key" if you are expecting the k.toString() to be identical that will not happen as you are constructing a different instance.... the key material should be the same though.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the k to a byte array and then to String:

```
byte[] kByte = k.getEncoded();
String encodedK = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(kByte)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per comments. Running...

```
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance("RC4");
        SecretKey k1 = kg.generateKey();
        String b64k1 = Base64.encode(k1.getEncoded());
        byte[] bk1 = Base64.decode(b64k1);
        SecretKey k2 = new SecretKeySpec( bk1, 0, bk1.length, "RC4");
        String b64k2 = Base64.encode(k2.getEncoded());
        byte[] bk2 = Base64.decode(b64k2);
        System.out.println(k1);
        System.out.println(k2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bk1));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bk2));
        System.out.println(b64k1);
        System.out.println(b64k2);
    }
```

Gives the following output:

```
javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@d36802be
javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@1b4e5
[107, -27, -118, -72, 46, -37, -57, -67, -84, 94, 20, 79, 123, 79, -50, 101]
[107, -27, -118, -72, 46, -37, -57, -67, -84, 94, 20, 79, 123, 79, -50, 101]
a+WKuC7bx72sXhRPe0/OZQ==
a+WKuC7bx72sXhRPe0/OZQ==
```

To clarify, k1.toString() and k2.toString() are only dependent on object instance in Object.toString() [default implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712139/why-does-the-default-object-tostring-include-the-hashcode#:%7E:text=The%20default%20toString()%20method,()%20method%20for%20more%20information.) and since k1 and k2 are distinct objects, the output is different. The actual key material is shown in next 4 lines as byte[] and then as base64 encoded String of that byte array and is equal as expected.

As an additional note, RC4 is [not considered safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4#Security) and should not be used in real production code.